The texture gone wrong after I applied "All transform"
I applied "All transform" to the right one, can anyone explain to me about this scenario?


Sure, if you create a shader which uses Texture Coordinates based on the object's location, rotation and scale (and they were not 0/0/0, 0°/0°/0° and 1/1/1 before), then everything gets messed up due to the new coordinates.
